# Why would we use BufferedStream for setting Buffer Size

Tags: c#, io

We can set the `buffersize` for Reading a File in `FileStream` itself.

```
FileStream fs=new FileStream(path,FileMode,FileAccess,FileShare,1024);
                                                                 ^
```

So why would we need `BufferedStream` if we can set buffer size in `FileStream` itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So why would we need BufferedStream if we can set buffer size in FileStream itself.

Because not every stream is a `FileStream`. What about `NetworkStream`? Or some other arbitrary stream? Or a situation where the code that needs buffering isn't the code that creates the stream? Being able to effectively add buffering post-construction can be very handy for writing general purpose code to work with *any* stream.

Comment: spot on..I was referring to NetworkStream and I thought it would be that way..But needed an expert's advice to be sure...:)